# How do I 'watch' list box selection change?

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net

In WPF VB.NET 4.0, I have a list box that is populated with a data binding from XML. How can I set a live watch event to the listbox so that the selected item, based on a certain criteria (field is true or false), a button on the form has it's content changed to read something else?

i.e., user selects an item with XML element 'status' is set to 'current', then button would read, Finished.
If user selects an item with XML element 'status' is set to 'finished', then button would read, Unfinished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `DataTrigger` for `Button.Content` that is bound to `ListBox.SelectedItem`

Here's an example button style that would display "Unfinished" by default, and change the text to "Finished" if `MyListBox.SelectedItem.Status = "Current"`. It assumes you have bound MyListBox to a collection of items which each contain a `Status` property

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyCustomButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Unfinished" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Status}" Value="Current">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Finished" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```